# Probability that fair die was thrown out of 3 dice ,the outcome being a prime number.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayes-theorem

There are three dice of which one is a fair die,the other two are false, one of the false dice has even numbers repeated twice and the other has odd numbers repeated twice. One die is chosen and thrown at random.If the outcome comes out to be a prime number, what is the probability that the fair die was chosen and thrown?

Comment: What are your thoughts? For each specific die, can you compute the probability that the toss is prime?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend not to reply well (or at all) to questions like this that look like routine homework problems and which show no effort at all.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  People will meet you half way if you show reasonable effort.

Comment: I 've been there Srinivas. Just don't write the question as it is. Show your input too. Take a look at my questions you 'll understand.

Comment: sorry about that , here's what I have tried   [link]https://imgur.com/a/td8axK9

Comment: I am not sure if the method I have used is correct.Really confused between the usage of conditional probability and Baye's theorem

Comment: Your method is fine but your algebra isn't.  Check the probability as concerns the fair die.

Comment: @lulu oops yeah it should be 1/2.My bad.

Comment: There you go.  Everything else looked good.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.